# Bass' stable range condition for principal ideal domains

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Do you know a characterization of commutative rings $R$ whose every prime factor ring of $R$ is a principal ideal domain?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sure. Let R be a commutative ring and for each prime ideal P of R, the ring of R/P is a principal ideal domain. Now I am searching to know what is this kind of rings?

Comment: And how does this relate to the Bass stable range condition?

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake. This question is in the ring Theory. There is no relation in this field. sorry for this mistake.